# Installing OpenCV on raspberry-pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, openwrt

How to install OpenCv on raspberry-pi (OpenWRT)? and what is the best programming language to use on the Linux running on the Rpi?

Comment: `best programming language` is very opinion-based, but I think a lot of people are recommending python on the Rpi, for some reason.

Comment: I would go with c++. I don't like interpreted languages.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already tried to add this [package](https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-devel/2008-August/003119.html) to OpenWrt. You could try to update the patch.

I've also found this [tutorial](http://mark4h.blogspot.de/2013/04/cross-compiling-opencv-for-openwrt.html).

If you don't necessarily need OpenWrt, you could use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). This distro provides OpenCV already and Python integration patches were already posted to its mailing list.